# MySQL EXCEPT equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, except

I am looking for MySQL equivalent or equivalents for the following query:

```sql
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Fall' and year= 2009)
except
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Spring' and year= 2010);
```

where the section table is:

```
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| course_id | sec_id | semester | year | building | room_number | time_slot_id |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| BIO-101   | 1      | Summer   | 2009 | Painter  | 514         | B            |
| BIO-301   | 1      | Summer   | 2010 | Painter  | 514         | A            |
| CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 | Packard  | 101         | H            |
| CS-101    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  | 101         | F            |
| CS-190    | 1      | Spring   | 2009 | Taylor   | 3128        | E            |
| CS-190    | 2      | Spring   | 2009 | Taylor   | 3128        | A            |
| CS-315    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Watson   | 120         | D            |
| CS-319    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Watson   | 100         | B            |
| CS-319    | 2      | Spring   | 2010 | Taylor   | 3128        | C            |
| CS-347    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 | Taylor   | 3128        | A            |
| EE-181    | 1      | Spring   | 2009 | Taylor   | 3128        | C            |
| EE-302    | 1      | Summer   | 2010 | Watson   | 327         | C            |
| FIN-201   | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  | 101         | B            |
| HIS-351   | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Painter  | 514         | C            |
| MU-199    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  | 101         | D            |
| PHY-101   | 1      | Fall     | 2009 | Watson   | 100         | A            |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

In other words I want to find all courses taught in the Fall 2009 semester but not in the Spring 2010 semester.

Comment: If you're querying this way frequently it might make sense to have a simple, easily indexed column that's a combination of semester and year, like `S2009` or `P2010` for Summer 2009 and Spring 2010 respectively. Also be certain you're using the correct quotes for your string values, as in the question those are smart-quotes and wrong.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I just copied it from the book and I forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `except`, so just use `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select courseid
from section sf
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009 and not exists
      (select 1
       from section ss
       where sf.courseid = ss.courseid and ss.semester = 'Spring' and ss.year = 2010
      );
```

(I prefer `not exists` because it has more intuitive support for `NULL` values.)

This is not exact, because `except` removes duplicates.  You *could* use `select distinct`, but I doubt that is really needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fond of sticking with JOINs when possible, and it is certainly possible here.

```
SELECT sFa.course_id
FROM section AS sFa
LEFT JOIN section AS sSpr 
   ON sFa.course_id = sSpr.course_id
   AND sSpr.semester = 'Spring' AND sSpr.year= 2010
WHERE sFa.semester = 'Fall' 
   AND sFa.year= 2009
   AND sSpr.course_id IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `not in` because `except` not available in mysql

```
select *
from section 
where courseid not in 
(
select courseid
from section
where semester = 'Spring' and year= 2010
) and semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exists` :

```
select s.*
from section s
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009 and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from section s1
                  where s.course_id = s1.course_id and 
                        s1.semester = 'Spring' and s1.year = 2010
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version [MySQL 8.0.31 update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html), you can now use the [`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html) operator natively. If you're allowed to update your MySQL version, you'll be able to run your code:

```
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Fall' and year= 2009)
except
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Spring' and year= 2010);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.course_id FROM section s
WHERE s.course_id IN ( 
 SELECT x.course_id FROM section x WHERE 
 x.semester="Fall" AND 
 x.year=2009 AND 
 x.semester<>"Spring" AND
 x.year<>2010
 );
```

Comment: Can you style the query better and explain what you've done so the asker gets more information?